# Windows Server 2008, Install Udates Without Reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have a server with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition 64-bit. *How can we install Windows updates without rebooting the server?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to install and *apply* the updates without rebooting.  The best way to answer this is to say this cannot be done.

There are some exceptions to this, patches to certain applications, when not in use, can be applied.  However, patches to kernel level files, operating system files, drivers, and in use applications cannot be applied without a reboot.

You *can* download and install updates without rebooting, but this is not recommended.  Some patches will stop services when installed, which could be detrimental to normal operation.

If you need 24x7 uptime, you need to look into clustering and/or virtualization.

Comment: Just to add: asking about that in the *enterprise* field would be out of scope for Super User